# Angular 6 - Having different scripts and styles for different layouts

Tags: javascript, css, angular, web

I'm trying to implement separate layouts for guest home page and admin page in an Angular 6 application. 
The thing is, I have two different templates, each with their js and css files.
I found a way to use styles on a component level, but for the scripts, I cannot find any way instead of having some method that will load all the scripts where I need them and when I need them. 
It's like, my guest home page uses totally different set of css styles and script files than my admin page. I know I should probably split my app into modules and then lazy load my modules, but I don't get it how I can make it to use different styles and scripts based on the page I'm currently visiting, or route. For now, i put my styles into a component that is my guest home page component, and I can do the same for admin and then separate them using parent and child routes, but how can i achieve the same for scripts and styles, without having loading them on the component level. Thank you.

Comment: "but how can i achieve the same for scripts and styles, without having loading them on the component level. Thank you." To do this, you have to create a component that has a <router-outlet>, applying your styles and scripts to this component, then rendering your other components into it. You can learn more about this here: https://blog.ng-book.com/basic-routing-in-angular-2/ and https://blog.angular-university.io/angular2-router/. Hope this helps, cheers.

Comment: Look at the comment I just posted. I mistakenly submitted the last one, now deleted.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but you didn't understand my problem. The thing is not to load any external scripts by usign <script> tags directly into html of the component, is to have them all bundled for specific parts of my application. If I'm visiting admin page, i want to load scripts just for admin template and so on. I know that i can do that on the component level by using some javascript to append script tags to my DOM, but that's not what I wanna have.

I already separated my app to use different layouts.

Answer (score 0):

i'll answer here and say that i've solved it by using separated service for loading scripts and will just inject the service in the component where i need it and provide id with an array of scripts that I need to have on that page.